# WICD silent installation

Tags: 14.04, bash, software-installation, wicd

I would like to install WICD without touching any key. I have it downloaded with all of dependencies in wicd directory

This is how line in BASH looks so far:

```
dpkg -R --install /usr/debs/wicd/ >/dev/null
```

Typically when you install WICD there is a question on blue screen in the middle of installation. I need to click ENTER then.

In my quiet installation the question is not show up but installation stop until i click ENTER.

How can i simulate ENTER click in bash ? Or is there any argument to run WICD installation without any questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

down loading the dependencies and installing manually sort of defeats the purpose of using the repositories and apt (apt-get).

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

To achieve what you want,

```
sudo -i
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -y install wicd
```

Comment: you are most welcome